# how to configure Pycharm settings so that the code gets printed as code scheme?

Tags: printing, pycharm, color-scheme

I have a color code, say, like this:

[image: ode]

I want to print this code on A4 paper just as shown above.

I did:

[image]

And result was not as I expected, for example: string "Test" at line 11 is printed as ocean blue [image]

So, I would really appreciate if someone could point out how to do it.

*(the printer is quite good at color printing)*

**P.S**: I can't use plugins since there have to be some url access, I may download any tar.gz or .whl file manually if there is any.

Comment: This is very subjective problem . Try to print by check or uncheck some of `Style` options

Comment: I did all combinations I guess

Comment: Hacky way is to screenshot part of code and print it as a picture.

Comment: Quite surprising this question was not answered for 3 years. Printing is not worth it with the lame color scheme used by default (some key words in blue, that's it).

Answer (score 0):

I did not find a direct solution but a workaround is to export to html: <File/Export/File or Selection to HTML> with the option "open in default browser checked. Then print from browser.